# Not allow a href tags in form textarea

Tags: php, html, regex

How can i prevent user to enter any url or link in contact form text area, i have tried it with this but its not working -

```
   if (!isset($_POST['submit']) && preg_match_all('/<a.*>.*<\/a>/', $_POST['query']))
      {
   echo "<h1 style='color:red;'>HTML Tag Not allowed </h1>";
      }
   else {
       //sendmail 
      }
```

Please help me

Comment: in general you should never attempt this kind of sanitation yourself, unless you have a really good reason to reinvent the wheel (and spend time weeding out all bugs). most mayor programming languages has native and solid/well tested functions for sanitizing html tags from text. in php it's strip_tags().

Comment: Perhaps a more important question: How can you prevent users from entering <script>-tags and hijacking your website through the contact form?

Answer (score 4):

## strip_tags

Try using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). It will allow you to strip out all tags that you don't allow.

### Examples

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

You would use something like this:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';

// Allow some tags but not <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><strong><li><ul>');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach doesn't work because, presumably, nobody would use formal HTML tags when posting a link. To sanitize the input, you could use the [PHP Strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Comment: I want to stop spams which mostly contains links or url, is there any way to that, i am very new so please support 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$regex_pattern = "/<a href=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/";

if( (strlen($_POST['query']) > 0) && (preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $_POST['query']) )
```

{
   echo "Tags found";
}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit']) and preg_match("/<a\shref=\"[a-z]{3,5}:\/{2}(?:w{3}\.)?[^>]+.([^<]+)/i",$_POST['query'])){
            //send mail
    }
```